# How to refresh a list in form A if user goes back to it from form B

Tags: java, codenameone

This is probably really simple to solve, but I've been stuck on this for a while. 
As the title suggests I have a ContainerList in Form A, which I want to refresh with new data if the user presses 'back navigation' from Form B. 
Form B was navigated to from clicking on a list element in Form A.
The code for Form A is not run if I use 'back' navigation to get to it.

I'm trying to do this in code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default back command from **Form B** and create a new one.

Create a new instance of **Form A** and show it inside the newly created back command.

If you are using gui builder forms, do this:

```
@Override
protected void beforeFormB(Form f) {
    f.removeAllCommand();
    f.setBackCommand(null);
    Command back = new Command("Back") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Form backForm = (Form) createContainer("/theme", "Form A");
            backForm.showBack();
            beforeShow(backForm);
            postShow(backForm);

            //If your form was hand coded, do this instead
            new FormA().showBack();
        }
    };
    back.putClientProperty("uiid", "BackCommand");
    f.setBackCommand(back);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a blank form A to display using your code. WIll this mean that I need a separate method for the form populating logic which gets called before Form A is shown to populate it? Thanks again.

Comment: The porblem is that now the back button on Form A takes me to Form B. Where as it needs to take me to Form 1. The sequence is Form 1-> Form A->Form B and back in that order.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include populating **Form A**. Could you edit your question to show the code you are using to show **Form B**?

Comment: I answered that myself. I have to explicitly state which form the back button takes the user to. I think I have solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help. I can only vote up once unfortunately :)

Comment: One finial thing, the animation for going back from form B to form A is now inverted. Instead of Form A appearing form the left side of the screen, it now appears from the right - as if we are going forward. Can I force it show a back transition?

Comment: One of these 2 will give you the desired behaviour `show()` and `showBack()`

Comment: Great, I got it working. Have to have a Boolean back flag so we know which transition direction to show. Thanks so much for your help.